# UriMatcher does not match a pattern

Tags: android, uri, android-contentprovider

I am creating a content provider for an android application, but I am having a problem correctly matching the uri using [UriMatacher](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/UriMatcher.html).

For example, I add the uri's to match (snipped from the link)

```
sURIMatcher.addURI("content://com.example", "people", PEOPLE);
sURIMatcher.addURI("content://com.example", "people/#", PEOPLE_ID);
sURIMatcher.addURI("content://com.example", "people/#/phones", PEOPLE_PHONES);
```

And then attempt to access `contacts/people/1/phones`. The successful match ends up being with `PEOPLE_ID` instead of `PEOPLE_PHONES`.

The query is initially generated by this code.

```
Uri uri = Uri.parse("content://com.example/people/#/phones");
ContentUris.appendId(uri.buildUpon(), 1).build();
```

With some logging statements thrown in, I see that the following:

The uri passed to the [query](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentProvider.html#query%28android.net.Uri,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D,%20java.lang.String%29) gives this:

```
content://com.example/people/1#/phones
```

but `uri.getPath()` gives this:

```
/people/1
```

The third path part of the uri is clearly dropped, which explains why it was matching the wrong uri.

The example from the Android developer website seems to indicate that there shouldn't be a problem with this. Am I creating the uri incorrectly? Is it just a bug? Is this intended functionality (and therefore the example from android developers is a bad one)?

Comment: Have You tried to exchange order of "people/#/phones" and "people/#" in sURIMatcher.addURI() calls?

Comment: I have tried changing orders, it didn't make a difference. I also tried completely removing everything except `people/#/phones`. In that case it just failed through to my default case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Uri.parse()` is ignorant of the `UriMatcher`'s wildcards; here, the `#` is the fragment identifier of a URI, so when you parse `content://com.example/people/#/phones`, it becomes `content://com.example/people` + fragment `/phones`. The id is correctly appended to the end of the URI, and then the fragment is carried over. In this case, you can't rely on `ContentUris`, but rather need to build the Uri the long way:

```
                path = new Uri.Builder()
                .scheme( ContentResolver.SCHEME_CONTENT )
                .authority( DataProvider.AUTHORITY )
                .appendPath( "people" )
                .appendPath( "1" )
                .appendPath( "phones" ) ).build();
```

Comment: From your comment I had just worked this out. It works perfectly

Comment: Glad I was able to help. The obvious shortcut is to use `String.format( Locale.US, "content://authority/people/%d/phones", id );`